# What are the vegetables that can be foraged or grown easily in West Bengal, India

Tags: vegetables

I am considering to compile a list of vegetables that could be foraged or grown easily in West Bengal, India.

Any pointer would be very helpful.

*Not sure if this question is appropriate for this forum.*

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "foraged"?  Do you mean that it grows wild, and you can wander around harvesting it?  Can you describe the climate, growing season, water availability, ambient temperature, and soil (how much clay, silt and sand; how deep; how is the drainage, etc.)?  Do you want to have a small garden by your house, or are you talking about farming?  If farming, are you looking to consume your produce, or do you want a cash crop?  What does wikipedia tell you about the primary crops grown there?

Comment: Great questions @aparente001.  By "foraged" I mean exactly what you mentioned, it grows wild, and you can wander around harvesting it. Climate is, tropical and the other conditions are similar to tropical region. Considering for kitchen garden for consumption, native vegetables that can grow on their own without much care.

Comment: Do you live in that region?  Perhaps local sources would be more reliable and comprehensive than this international mélange. / There is a large variety of soils and ecosystems within the term "tropical."